# Qt5 Remote Objects + custom type but not in POD

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtremoteobjects

I would like to use loads of custom objects with Qt5 remote objects.
As I read they might not needed to be created as PODs in the .REP file.
I have tried to do the following:

```
namespace my::api {
    class Card {
        Q_GADGET

        Q_PROPERTY(QString type READ type WRITE setType)
        [... removed property functions]
        Q_PROPERTY(QString id READ id WRITE setId)
        [... removed property functions]

        public:
        static void declareQML() {
            qRegisterMetaType<my::api::Card>("Card");
        }
    };

    inline QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const my::api::Card & value) {
        stream << value.type() << value.id();
        return stream;
    }

    inline QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& stream, quint::api::Card & value) {
        QString tmp;
        stream >> tmp;
        value.setType(tmp);

        stream >> tmp;
        value.setId(tmp);

        return stream;
    }

    class Result {
        Q_GADGET

        Q_PROPERTY(bool status READ status WRITE setStatus NOTIFY statusChanged)
    public:
        bool status() { return m_status; }
    public slots:
        void setStatus(bool p) { m_status = p;  emit statusChanged(); }
    private:
        bool m_status;

    public:

        static void declareQML() {
            qRegisterMetaType<my::api::Result>("Result");
        }

        Result() : m_code(false) {}
    };

    inline QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const my::api::Result & value) {
        stream << value.status();
        return stream;
    }

    inline QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& stream, my::api::Result & value) {
        bool tmp;
        stream >> tmp;
        value.setStatus(tmp);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Then do something like that in the .REP:

```
SLOT(checkCard(my::api::Card card));
SIGNAL(checkCardResponse(my::api::Result result));
```

However I get

```
Trying to construct an instance of an invalid type, type id: 1073676288
Trying to construct an instance of an invalid type, type id: 655615
Trying to construct an instance of an invalid type, type id: 1073676288
```

from the client, when I try to do a checkCard().

all the declareQML stuff is called right after starting the application
(before the replica is created).

Can anyone post me a complete/working example how to use custom classes
with QT5 Remote Objects without creating the custom classes as PODs in the
REP file?

Comment: It is definitly possible, as I have done it before. I see you register the types with an explicit name without a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` beforehand. That could be the reason why it does not work (as Qt now only knows of a type named "Card", but in the rep file you want a type named "my::api::Card", thus the invalid type)

Comment: Hmm I have tried qRegisterMetaType with (“my::api::Card””) or with simply (), but didn’t help at all. The sad part is that I also dumped on screen the type id of the structure, but that was a very different number

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turned out that the issue had nothing to do with the passed structure. I had a 
PROP in the REP which could not be generated, so practically the system was crashing right when it tried to instantiate the replica.